# Как расположить горизонтально меню?

Tags: css

Подскажите, как правильно расположить горизонтально меню в шапке, чтобы до разрешения **1024px** пункты меню были в одну строку?

T.е. чтобы пункт меню и текст не переносились на новую строку при уменьшении разрешения экрана.

Для ссылок ещё нужен **`hover`**, чтобы при наведении ссылка выделялась другим цветом.

Т.е. при данном количестве пунктов меню должно быть прижато слева и справа к краям родителя. А если пунктов меньше, пусть будет прижато влево.

Т.е. нужен адаптив

```css
header {
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
  width: 95%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

aside {
  width: 19.91%;
  flex-basis: 19.91%;
  max-width: 281px;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.links {
  width: 80.09%;
  flex-basis: 80.09%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

.links-ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 18px 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .2s;
}

a:hover,
a.active {
  background: #bd3534;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 18px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>
      aside
    </aside>
    <nav class="links">
      <ul class="links-ul">
        <li><a href="about.html">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="actions.html">Акции и скидки</a></li>
        <li><a href="delivery.html">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
        <li><a href="answers.html">Вопросы и ответы</a></li>
        <li><a href="reviews.html">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="seasons.html">Сезонный повод</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Покажите картинкой как должно выглядеть, мне лично из вашего описания не понятно ничего.

Comment: Не возникало мысли, сделать размер шрифта поменьше?

Comment: конкретнее опиши, покажи на картинке как надо.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .links ul{
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        outline: 1px solid #fff;
    }
```

Comment: нет, текст всё ещё переносится

Comment: Пропишите отдельный класс для ul и установите ему display: inline-flex;

Comment: не работает с классом, не в классе дело

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen  and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .links-ul>li{ width: 180px;
                 font-family: Arial;
                 padding: 0px;
                 text-align: center;}
}
```

Comment: выше ведь сказано, что до разрешения 1024px, и ваш пример ничего не меняет

Comment: так кто-то подскажет, как это сделать?

Comment: я так понял это слишком сложный вопрос?

Comment: @media only screen  and (min-width : 1024px) {
    .links-ul>li{ width: 180px;
                 font-family: Arial;
                 padding: 0px;
                 text-align: center;}
}

Comment: вы внимательно читали?  во первых 180px для каждого пункта из 8ми, будет 1440px, что уже больше нужного. И там разная ширина у текста, тут нужно паддинг

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы текст шёл в одну строку, добавьте: `white-space: nowrap;` в li или a.
Например:

```
li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Может прозвучать тупо, но как по мне, вам нужно просто увеличить ширину элементов меню, затем уменьшить padding

Comment: т.е. для каждого пункта меню задавать ширину? это будет не адаптив

Comment: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/ вот, посмотрите как можно сделать меню с помощью @media

Comment: либо,если не хотите использовать media breakpoints, тогда используйте  сетку того же bootsrap или materializecss

Comment: а что там можно увидеть полезного из вашей ссылки? список пустых медиа-запросов? и сетка не нужна

Comment: как правильно подобрать паддинг и размер шрифта для ссылок?

Comment: @media only screen  and (max-width : 1024px) {
 padding:сколько вам надо
}

Comment: через консоль f12 посмотрите как элементы будут себя вести в зависимости от изменяемого паддинга